# Selecting the first leaf node of a tree panel in ExtJs 4.1

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1 TreePanel control. When user clicks on a button, I want to select the first leaf node of the tree panel and then fire the select or itemClick event. What is the best approach for getting the desired result.

So far I am using this code:

```
 var root = Ext.getStore('MyStore').getRootNode();
 var firstChildNode = root.findChild('leaf', true, true);
 Ext.getCmp('treePnl').getSelectionModel().select(firstChildNode);
```

**Is there any better way to select a node in ExtJs tree panel and how can I fire select or itemClick event of the tree panel?**

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var root = Ext.getStore('MyStore').getRootNode(),
    tree = Ext.getCmp('treePnl'),
    selModel  = tree.getSelectionModel();

selModel.select(root.firstChild);

tree.fireEvent('itemselect', root.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the 'leaf' is further down in the tree I used the following
working solution:

```
// select first leaf
var item = tree.getRootNode();
while(item.firstChild)
    { item = item.firstChild; }

tree.getSelectionModel().select(item);
```